# Can't simultaneously use makecell, threeparttable and tabulary

Tags: tables, threeparttable, tabulary, makecell

I'm trying to accomplish "threeparttables" while simultaneously using both `makecell` (to achieve within-cell rowbreaks) and `tabulary` (to make the tables not exceed `\linewidth`). But while I can achieve threeparttables with `tabulary` that don't use `makecell` (first code example below) and tables with `tabulary` that use `makecell` but not `threeparttable` (second code example below), I can't build a document that combines the three (third example). What to do?

I am aware that using `tabularx` instead of `tabulary` builds this particular table, but I have lots of these tables. I would prefer not to check each table separately but instead use `tabulary`. Also, I am not married to using `makecell` but I need to be able to have rowbreaks within cells (and to control their vertical alignment).

Any help would be much appreciated!

**First example** (`threeparttable` and `tabular` but no `makecell`)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[para]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\begin{document}
  \begin{table}
    \begin{threeparttable}
      \caption{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur}

      {
        \begin{tabulary}{\linewidth}{L r L r}
        \textbf{Aaa} & \textbf{Bbb} & \textbf{Ccc} \tabularnewline
         & & Ccc1 & Ccc2 \tabularnewline
        Adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor & \(0.40\) & Ut labore et dolore magna aliqua & \(7.77\) \tabularnewline
        Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation & \(0.93\) & Ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat & \(62.6\) \tabularnewline
        \end{tabulary}
      }
    \end{tablenotes}
  \end{threeparttable}
\end{document}
```

**Second example** (`tabulary` and `makecell` but no `threeparttable`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{makecell}
\begin{document}
  \begin{table}
    \caption{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur}

    {
      \begin{tabulary}{\linewidth}{L r L r}
      \textbf{Aaa} & \textbf{Bbb} & \textbf{Ccc} \tabularnewline
       & & \makecell{Ccc1} & \makecell{Ccc2 \\ Ccc2} \tabularnewline
      Adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor & \(0.40\) & Ut labore et dolore magna aliqua & \(7.77\) \tabularnewline
      Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation & \(0.93\) & Ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat & \(62.6\) \tabularnewline
      \end{tabulary}
    }
  \end{table}
\end{document}
```

**Third example** (all three, not working)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[para]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{makecell}
\begin{document}
  \begin{table}
    \begin{threeparttable}
      \caption{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur}

      {
        \begin{tabulary}{\linewidth}{L r L r}
        \textbf{Aaa} & \textbf{Bbb} & \textbf{Ccc} \tabularnewline
         & & \makecell{Ccc1} & \makecell{Ccc2 \\ Ccc2} \tabularnewline
        Adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor & \(0.40\) & Ut labore et dolore magna aliqua & \(7.77\) \tabularnewline
        Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation & \(0.93\) & Ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat & \(62.6\) \tabularnewline
        \end{tabulary}
      }

      \begin{tablenotes}
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
      \end{tablenotes}
    \end{threeparttable}
  \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace `\makecell` with the `\Centerstack` command from `stackengine`, which doesn't have a conflict with other packages:

```
\usepackage[latin]{babel} 
\usepackage[para]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}

\begin{document}

  \begin{table}
    \begin{threeparttable}
      \caption{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur}

      {
        \begin{tabulary}{\linewidth}{L r L r}
        \textbf{Aaa} & \textbf{Bbb} & \textbf{Ccc} \tabularnewline
         & & \Centerstack{Ccc1} & \Centerstack{Ccc2\\ Ccc2} \tabularnewline
        Adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor & \(0.40\) & Ut labore et dolore magna aliqua & \(7.77\) \tabularnewline
        Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation & \(0.93\) & Ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat & \(62.6\) \tabularnewline
        \end{tabulary}
      }

      \begin{tablenotes}\footnotesize
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
      \end{tablenotes}
    \end{threeparttable}
  \end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: When this (or `\Longunderstack` that I ended up using) is combined with `\strutlongstacks{T}`, it looks just like what I intended :)